# How to achieve a similar "vibe" to this song?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, composition

I want to write a song similar to ["dumb dumb" by mazie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPJxch3AdKo). I want to achieve a similar feel of weird, dreamy nostalgia the song has. I know a lot of this feeling comes from dissonance between descending chromatics and diatonic tones, but is there any other things I need to keep in mind when writing a song like this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my first attempt at contributing to the Music Theory Forum so please forgive if I completely screw it up!  Anyhow, I've taken the liberty of transcribing the beginning of the song:

[image: Dumb Finale Screenshot]

The thing that stands out for me in this the chromaticism is bars two and four which lean on the D augmented chord.  This lends the song its characteristically "whimsical" element that you often see in showtunes (for lack of a better term) and the like.   Reduced to its most basic form it frequently appears in Broadway (often as a vamp) as such:

[image: Simple Broadway Vamp]

Or, in a slightly more "jaunty" form:

[image: Jauntier Broadway Vamp]

Also adding to the style is the minor chord in bar 8 that again uses the raised sixth/flat seventh degree of D major for chromatic coloration, this time resolving downwards.

Other things that create this slightly surreal/dreamy/nostalgic effect are  the colorful instrument timbres/effects, the generally light texture and the slightly understated singing in the, for lack of a better term, Lily Allen style.